# Symfony2: Checkboxes and form->setData()

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class form:

```
class MyForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options = array())
    {
        $builder->add('types', 'choice', array(
            'choices'       => $options['data']['types'],
            'required'      => false,
            'multiple'      => true,
            'expanded'      => true,
        ));

        $builder->add('dateFrom', 'date', array(
            'years' => range(date('Y') - 5, date('Y')),
            'required' => false,
        ));
    }
}
```

In my controller I do next:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TransSearchForm, array(
    'types' => $myCheckboxArray
));

// getting form data from required
$data = $this->getRequest()->get($form->getName());

/*... some changes dateFrom param in $data array ...*/

$form->setData($data);
```

And checked checkboxes not checked(
But if I use

```
$form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());
```

all working correct - checked checboxes are checked. But my dateFrom param not changed...

So, I need:
1) change dateFrom param manually
2) view checkboxes checked after send form

Using bindRequest or setData - no matter. Can somebody help me?

Comment: How you are changing the dateFrom param?

Comment: If param is empty, I set default value:
if (!$data['dateFrom']) $data['dateFrom'] = new \DateTime($dateFrom);

Comment: I never had used forms without entity, but you should listen to  `POST_BIND ` event in your form, and provider a default `dateFrom` there. Then use `bindRequest()`, it will work. See: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html